# Isolated Scope '=' passes a string instead of the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to pass a model (Object) into the scope of the directive but it is passing a string instead of the object.

The directive html.

```
<blabla obj="obj"></blabla>
```

Directive:

```
.directive( 'blabla' , function(){
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    scope :{
        obj : '=obj'
    },
    link : function(scope , elem , attrs){ console.log(attrs);
      scope.obj = attrs.obj;
    }
}})
```

Then in the controller I have:

```
$scope.obj = { name : "obj"};
```

And this is what I get in the console

```
obj: "obj"
```

Am I missing something? Why is it rendering 'obj' as a String instead of fetching the object? If I print the object on the page it works, but it doesn't work to pass it into the directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use attrs.obj. 
You should already have obj on the scope once the link function is run